# Appcelerator caching techniques. Feedback wanted!

Tags: caching, appcelerator

Titanium SDK version: 1.6.1 
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am trying to build a solution to cache JSON calls. I have done a first attempt that does the job, but is there a better solution? I am using textfiles to save the JSON output, is this OK performance wise?

http://pastie.org/1734763

Thankful for all feedback!

Comment: I like it overall, but I'd move the caching code into a module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that'd be ok. As long as the files aren't massive in number/size it should perform quite well.

The other approach you could try if you decide you're not happy with performance, or want to maintain less code, is to use App storage, which persists data beyond app sessions.

```
Titanium.App.setString('jsonResponse', this.responseText);
Titanium.App.setInt('expires', this.responseText.expires);
```

Then before you make your request you can check if the cache is indeed stale:

```
var expires = Titanium.App.getInt('expires');

// Get the current time in milliseconds, etc.

if(expires > current_time) {
    // Cache is still valid
    var response = Titanium.App.getString('jsonResponse');
    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
}
else {
    // Cache is stale - query for new data
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting! Which one is better in your opinion with regards to performance and maintainability? App Storage or filesystem?

Comment: Performance-wise I'd imagine they'd be about the same; under the hood I'd guess that the contents of the storage are being eventually written to a plist file anyway. There may be some optimisations, though, e.g. when the app is open it may be stored in memory which would be faster. I'm afraid that's just a guess though, you'd have to try it and see! Maintainability wise there may slightly less code involved for the App storage approach, but it'd be marginal. I think both approaches are viable, it's down to preference really.

Comment: Thank you Craig for your input!

Comment: No worries, hope it's useful!

Comment: Another thing. Using your example how exactly is the caching process working? The data I am requesting from the API need to be up to date (contact data). Is this a good approach for this kind of data? Using your example isn´t the system downloading new data all the time since the cached file is always older than the current request? Sorry for all my questions :) I need to understand the best concept of caching.

Comment: I didn't make that very clear, my apologies. There's a few approaches you could take. When you download the contact data you could include a field which indicates how long data should be cached for (like the HTTP cache-control / expires headers). You can then check against this to see if you should request data. Alternatively, if you have to always have up-to-date info but want to limit the amount of data you download, you can query your webservice to see if new data is available (a relatively smaller request), and only update if the service indicates you should. I've updated the example.